# How to config xdebug with Vagrant and PhpStorm: Exit code 255?

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to configure xdebug to work with my Vagrant VM in PhpStorm. I tried using [this guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/install-xdebug-phpstorm-vagrant/) but to no avail.
I've already got xdebug installed on my Vagrant box and the box is also registered and configured with PhpStorm

I have tried setting a break point and running the debugger on this basic test function with Laravel:

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    $a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    array_pop($a);

    return 'hello';
});
```

But it fails with the following error message:

```
vagrant://C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\myproject/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2 /vagrant/app/routes.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Route' not found in /vagrant/app/routes.php on line 6
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /vagrant/app/routes.php:0

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I also tried running it on a function in one of my controllers but it gives a similar error

```
vagrant://C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\myproject/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2 /vagrant/app/controllers/MyController.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'BaseController' not found in /vagrant/app/controllers/MyController.php on line 15
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /vagrant/app/controllers/MyController.php:0

Process finished with exit code 255
```

/etc/php5/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.idekey = "vagrant"
```

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Config Github Settings
github_username = "johndoe"
github_repo     = "myrepo"
github_branch   = "master"

# Server Configuration

# Set a local private network IP address.
# See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network for explanation
# You can use the following IP ranges:
#   10.0.0.1    - 10.255.255.254
#   172.16.0.1  - 172.31.255.254
#   192.168.0.1 - 192.168.255.254
server_ip             = "192.168.22.10"
server_memory         = "384" # MB
server_timezone       = "UTC"


# HHVM Options
hhvm_use_fastcgi      = "false"  # Use HHVM as FastCGI (over php-fpm)
hhvm_over_php         = "false"  # Symlink HHVM to PHP, so calls to PHP run via HHVM

# PHP Options
php_version           = "previous" # Options: latest|previous|distributed   For 12.04. latest=5.5, previous=5.4, distributed=5.3

public_folder         = "" # If installing Symfony or Laravel, leave this blank to default to the framework public directory
laravel_version       = "4.1.27"
laravel_root_folder   = "/vagrant/laravel" # Where to install Laravel. Will `composer install` if a composer.json file exists
symfony_root_folder   = "/vagrant/symfony" # Where to install Symfony.


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # Set server to Ubuntu 12.04
  config.vm.box = "precise64"

  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  # Create a hostname, don't forget to put it to the `hosts` file
  # This will point to the server's default virtual host
  # TO DO: Make this work with virtualhost along-side xip.io URL
  config.vm.hostname = "vaprobash.dev"

  # Create a static IP
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: server_ip


  # If using VirtualBox
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|

    # Set server memory
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", server_memory]

    # Set the timesync threshold to 10 seconds, instead of the default 20 minutes.
    # If the clock gets more than 15 minutes out of sync (due to your laptop going
    # to sleep for instance, then some 3rd party services will reject requests.
    vb.customize ["guestproperty", "set", :id, "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold", 10000]

  end

  # If using VMWare Fusion
  config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |vb, override|
    override.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64_vmware.box"

    # Set server memory
    vb.vmx["memsize"] = server_memory

  end

  # If using Vagrant-Cachier
  # http://fgrehm.viewdocs.io/vagrant-cachier
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-cachier")
    # Configure cached packages to be shared between instances of the same base box.
    # Usage docs: http://fgrehm.viewdocs.io/vagrant-cachier/usage
    config.cache.scope = :box

    config.cache.synced_folder_opts = {
        type: :nfs,
        mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp', 'nolock']
    }
  end

  ####
  # Base Items
  ##########

  # Provision Base Packages
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "https://raw.github.com/#{github_username}/#{github_repo}/#{github_branch}/scripts/base.sh"

  # Provision PHP
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "https://raw.github.com/#{github_username}/#{github_repo}/#{github_branch}/scripts/php.sh", args: [php_version, server_timezone]

  ####
  # Web Servers
  ##########

  # Provision Apache Base
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "https://raw.github.com/#{github_username}/#{github_repo}/#{github_branch}/scripts/apache.sh", args: [server_ip, public_folder]

  ####
  # Frameworks and Tooling
  ##########

  # Provision Composer
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "https://raw.github.com/#{github_username}/#{github_repo}/#{github_branch}/scripts/composer.sh", privileged: false, args: composer_packages.join(" ")

  # Provision Laravel
  #config.vm.provision "shell", path: "https://raw.github.com/#{github_username}/#{github_repo}/#{github_branch}/scripts/laravel.sh", privileged: false, args: [server_ip, laravel_root_folder, public_folder, laravel_version]

end
```

PhpStorm version: 8.0.2

It seems like xdebug is not able to read any of the Laravel classes/facades. What can I do to get this fixed so I can use xdebug?

Comment: This is PHP issue (to be precise: your configuration, possibly the way how you have configured your Laravel project) and has **nothing** to do with xdebug. Xdebug only gets involved when PHP is executing the script. If PHP is unable to find the script to execute (file with `Route` class etc) then how it could be an xdebug issue.

Comment: I also want to point out that for me it looks like you are trying to execute your PHP code in a CLI environment (SSH) and not via browser -- is this what you intended to do?

Comment: It is executing over ssh on my remote/guest Vagrant machine, but I have this machine configured within PhpStorm. When I click `Run->Debug` in PhpStorm, it shows the ssh dialog, and then brings up the debug console and shows me the error message. It's definitely a configuration issue, because the code runs fine in the browser when not using `Run->Debug`. And so I'm just trying to figure out how to get this configured properly.

Comment: Watch this first ( http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/ ). You are doing it wrong (my thought) -- debugging a CLI script is not what you need here -- simply because Run/Debug can mean a lot of things -- it all depends on type of your Run/Debug configuration.